# How explosive is rhydonium?

Tags: star-wars

As far as I have read, it is known that rhydonium is an extremely volatile substance that has the potential to cause massive explosions. Yet, in season one of *Rebels*, when Hera and Sabine used the canisters of rhydonium to defend themselves against the fyrnocks, the explosions didn't seem to be that big. Judging from the number of canisters they exploded, I expected a much bigger and more dangerous explosion than what occurred. So, how explosive is rhydonium exactly? I searched around Wookieepedia, but couldn't find very much information about ryhdonium.

Comment: Surely it's proportional to the amount used. [Some](https://www.facebook.com/WordisBondPDX/videos/stick-of-tnt-dynamite-from-wwii-exploding-300-feet-in-front-of-us-the-interns-re/482109355545472/) versus [lots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VANyY87-_Q)

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rhydonium

Comment: I guess that's the difference between refined and unrefined Rhydonium. refined rhydonium is fuel (less explosive) compared to the unrefined type.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. Those answers were quite helpful! (:

Comment: What units would you like the answer in? Parsecs?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I wasn't particularly looking for a specific unit of measurement. But, if you can give me an answer in a defined measurement, that would be helpful, too. Thanks!